# dagster: run every hour and pass last execution time to asset

Tags: python, dagster

I'm new to dagster to please be patient for not fully grasping it yet.

I want to "run an asset" every hour which should be possible with schedules. What i also want is to pass the last execution date into the asset. This is used to fetch only data modified since the last call.

So the issue is 2-fold:

- How do I store the last execution date?
- How do I load the last exectuion date upon execution and pass it to the asset?

Answer (score 1):

You can of course create the hourly schedule like below:

```
@hourly_schedule(
    pipeline_name='test_pipeline',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 06, 14),
    execution_time=datetime.time(hour=datetime.now().hour, minute=0),
)
```

and then you can try extracting the last execution date from the context of the dag

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def hourly_schedule(context):
    last_execution_time = context.scheduled_execution_time - timedelta(hours=1)
```

finally you can pass it to the asset

```
    context.asset_store.set_asset(
        key='last_execution_time',
        obj=last_execution_time,
    )
```

Comment: what are the guarantees here that there isn't  a small gap between execution times? especially running 1 second late for example that would miss any changes made in that 1 second.